# Defining and using an object passed from Express to EJS

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

In my route handler I pass an object (the object is the result of a SELECT query to database) to my ejs file that is rendered as follows:

```
const query = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM table');
const obj = query.rows();
response.render('/ejspage', {
   obj: obj
});
```

In my ejs file I am then trying to assign this object to a variable and loop through it:

```
<script>
   var data = '<%= obj %>';

   data.forEach(function(o) {
      console.log(o);
   }
</script>
```

This causes the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: obj.forEach is not a function`

I have tried using `JSON.parse(obj)` but this results in the following error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

I've also tried `JSON.stringify(obj)` to resolve the error with no luck

When I print out the variable `console.log(obj)` I get:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I know that I can use embedded javascript in ejs (when I do this I can use forEach() on obj just fine) but for my specific purpose I would like to do it the way shown (i.e. within the `<script>` tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use both `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```
 <script>
   var data = JSON.parse('<%= JSON.stringify(obj) %>');

   data.forEach(function(o) {
      console.log(o);
   }
</script>
```

i found that in some cases that `JSON parse` of `JSON stringify` still gave error and took inspiration from a post doing cookie parse

```
 <script>
   var data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent('<%=encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(data) ) %>')) 

   data.forEach(function(o) {
      console.log(o);
   }
</script>
```

a alternative is using `res.cookie` but it is limited to 4 MB

Comment: Doesn't using ```JSON.parse``` and ```JSON.stringify``` just negate each other? Another solution I found was to do the following: var data = <%- JSON.stringify(obj) %>;,  which then allows me to iterate through obj using .forEach()

Comment: to code inside <% %> is ran server side , basically `JSON.stringify` will transform the object in string and add to the html page that's being sent to client, and then when the browser loads the page it will transform the string in to object (using `JSON.parse`)